# How to skip a form element from TAB navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

If I use <kbd>TAB</kbd> on the keyboard then the cursor goes from 1 to 4 (1 → 2 → 3 → 4)

How can I skip number 3? I would like go 1 → 2 → 4.

```
<table>
    <tr><td> <input type="text" value="1"></td><td><input type="text" value="2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td> <input type="text" value="3"></td><td><input type="text" value="4"></td></tr>
</table>
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/49Vca/

Comment: Do you want it (3) to be select-able via mouse but not via Tab key ?
What about Arrows, or direct access (hitting value on keyboard) ?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you set the tabindex = "-1" on the input itself of #3, you won't be able to tab to #3

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [tabIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_tabindex.asp) property

Answer (score 2):

Give the elements ID, and write a script on these lines...

```
function changeTabIndex()
  {
  document.getElementById('1').tabIndex="1"
  document.getElementById('2').tabIndex="2"
  document.getElementById('3').tabIndex="-1"
  document.getElementById('4').tabIndex="3"
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why set it via script? Makes no sense.

Comment: the op had tagged it with javascript and jQuery so I assumed he needed to do the same using js......my bad

Comment: Hm… the OP has tagged it with every conceivable tag. :) But yes, from that POV the answer is valid. +1

Comment: the answer is valid, except in the fact that 'legally' you aren't supposed to have an ID that starts with a number..  and you don't actually need to set the tabindex for 1 2 or 4 because not having tabIndex at all browsers assume tabIndex of 0 which the tab index becomes the order in which they appear in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

If using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) is ok, you can try [SkipOnTab](https://joelpurra.com/projects/skipontab/).

> [SkipOnTab](https://joelpurra.com/projects/skipontab/): A jQuery plugin to exempt selected form fields from the forward tab order.

Just add `data-skip-on-tab="true"` to the elements (or containers) you want to skip. You can still click to focus them or go back using <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>.

In your case:

```html
<table>
    <tr><td> <input type="text" value="1"></td><td><input type="text" value="2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td> <input type="text" value="3" data-skip-on-tab="true"></td><td><input type="text" value="4"></td></tr>
</table>
```

See [the simple demo](https://joelpurra.com/projects/skipontab/docs/example/demo.html) and [the business case demo](https://joelpurra.com/projects/skipontab/docs/example/skip-some-fields-in-order-form.html). You can also [try the forked jsfiddle with SkipOnTab](http://jsfiddle.net/uMrN6/).

Comment: For the downvoter: I built the plugin to add functionality (predictable order, shift-tab), not to do the exact same thing as pure HTML `tabindex="-1"`. See https://github.com/joelpurra/skipontab/wiki/SkipOnTab-versus-tabindex

Answer (score -1):

Assuming there is a reason 3 needs to remain tabbable (such as an MVC view where the element is an input control and needs to remain part of the tab order, or else it won't send data back to the controller), you probably won't be able to actually skip it in both directions, and if you do find a way, it will depend on a bug that will be patched out without warning to bring the browser back into compliance with the W3 specifications regarding tab order.

To skip in either the forward or reverse direction (but not both!), add an onfocusin() event handler to element 3, that calls focus() on the element immediately following or preceding it. If onfocus events were still allowed to pass the previously focused control in the event parameter (as event.relatedTarget), you could tell what the previously focused element was, and transfer control to the previous element if focus came from the next element. However, the W3 specification makes it clear that this is not compliant behavior, and HTML5-compliant browsers are required to pass null for event.relatedTarget, and do everything else in their capabilities to prevent any focus() event handler from having access to the identity of the previously focused control, specifically nulling out any such field before either a focus() or blur() event handler is called in client-side code.